# Sitecore Azure module cache setting

Tags: azure, sitecore

Site is hosted on Azure. Recently a new content delivery server was configured for traffic manager to split traffic between two content delivery servers / databases.

The problem whenever we publish the cache does not clear for the *new* database, so viewing the URL endpoint for that database shows old content. 
It is our theory that the cache for this new CD database is not being cleared.

If the server resets / restarts, the caches clear, and the content can be seen on all URLs as expected.

Is there any configuration change that needs to be done for cache setting when adding new servers to Sitecore Azure

Example:

- A change is made on CMS and published to both targets.
- Change is pushed up through to all targets (Staging, West, East) and 
  can be seen in CMS
- Change is observed on direct URL for West DB
- Change is **not seen** on direct url for East DB

Answer (score 0):

No there shouldn't be any need to change the settings per environment but it should be noted that the azure module sets up the new deployment with default settings and not with any changes that you may have made to your existing one in the deployment items under the azure module.

Are you using the same site on both environments? if not then you may need to add the one that isn't working to the publish:end and publish:end:remote events in the web.config.

Like this:

```
<event name="publish:end">
    <handler type="Sitecore.Publishing.HtmlCacheClearer, Sitecore.Kernel" method="ClearCache">
      <sites hint="list">
        <site>website</site>
        <site>Test</site>
      </sites>
    </handler>
  </event>
  <event name="publish:end:remote">
    <handler type="Sitecore.Publishing.HtmlCacheClearer, Sitecore.Kernel" method="ClearCache">
      <sites hint="list">
        <site>website</site>
        <site>Test</site>
      </sites>
    </handler>
  </event>
```

Comment: I just edited my question to add in more details. Yes we are using the same site on both the environments.
But here is an example of what we are running into

Example:

A change is made on CMS and published to both targets.
Change is pushed up through to all targets (Staging, West, East) and can be seen in CMS
Change is observed on direct URL for West DB
Change is not seen on direct url for East DB

Comment: does the change show up if you manually clear the cache on the east DB?

Comment: Yes, as a temporary fix we force clear the cache very 6 hrs using a schedule task.

Comment: is the CA server in the 'West' data centre? are event queues turned on? I would expect that they are but I wanted to check. One thing I found is that its best to share a core database, for 7.2 anyway. There is no documentation that says you have to share a core database but there are reasons that you need to. Also it could be possible that the event queues can't connect to each other due to being in different data centres. I think you are supposed to maintain a CA server in each data centre and sync the master db using azure to get content changes